# Dividing elements of a list by their positions

Tags: list-manipulation

How to divide each element of a list by its position?

I have a list

```
t1 = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29};
```

and want to divide each element by its `Position` yielding

```
{2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 11/5, 13/6, 17/7, 19/8, 23/9, 29/10}
```

It can be done by

```
Flatten[#/Flatten[Position[t1, #]] & /@ t1]
```

which looks awful. Any better ideas (without using `Range`)?

Comment: Table[t1[[i]]/i, {i, Length[t1]}]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[#1/First[#2] &, t1]
```

or

```
#/Range[Length[#]] &[t1]
```

All return:

```
(* Out: {2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 11/5, 13/6, 17/7, 19/8, 23/9, 29/10} *)
```

Comment: t1/Range@Length@t1 is a great code-golf version of this! It manages for repeated values, too! AND keeps the ordering! Nice work, MarcoB!

Answer (score 5):

For this specific list (list of primes) one can do:

```
Array[ Prime[#]/# &, 10]
```

or in more general case:

```
Array[ t1[[#]]/# &, 10]
```

Nonetheless I still find `Range` the most efficient and elegant:

```
t1/Range[10]
```

> ```
>  {2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 11/5, 13/6, 17/7, 19/8, 23/9, 29/10}
> ```

or `t1/Range[ Length[t1]]`.

Answer (score 5):

For the particular `t1` in OP:

```
t1 / PrimePi[t1]
```

> ```
>  {2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 11/5, 13/6, 17/7, 19/8, 23/9, 29/10}
> ```

In general,

```
(i = 1; Map[# / i++ &]) @ t1
```

> ```
> {2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 11/5, 13/6, 17/7, 19/8, 23/9, 29/10}
> ```

```
lookMaNoRange = Accumulate[1 & /@ #] &;
t1 / lookMaNoRange[t1]
```

> ```
> {2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 11/5, 13/6, 17/7, 19/8, 23/9, 29/10}
> ```

```
lookMaNoRange2 = (i = 1; Map[i++ &]);
t1 / lookMaNoRange2[t1]
```

> ```
> {2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 11/5, 13/6, 17/7, 19/8, 23/9, 29/10}
> ```

etc...

Comment: `lookMaNoRange` <— that made me laugh hehehe

Comment: You are a fox! Cunning as ever!

Answer (score 4):

```
KeyValueMap[Splice[#1/#2]&, PositionIndex@t1]
```

or

```
KeyValueMap[#1/#2&, PositionIndex@t1]//Flatten
```

> {2, 3/2, 5/3, 7/4, 11/5, 13/6, 17/7, 19/8, 23/9, 29/10}

Comment: Though solution no. 1 does not not work in my version, I learnt new things from no. 2. Great!

Comment: Nice work. This manages for repeated values (though changes the ordering) unlike my solution using `PositionIndex`

Answer (score 3):

This might only work if there’s no duplicates

```
PositionIndex@t1//{Keys[#],Values[#]}&//Transpose//(#[[1]]/#[[2,1]])&/@#&
```

Comment: Wow! Your style is different!